# timepicker jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery

i am using jQuery to plugin in and want to create a input field that i could select time. How come it doesn't work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.min.css">


    <input id="datetime">

    <script>
        $("#datetime").datetimepicker();
    </script>
```

and above is my path.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any error at developer console of browser ?

Comment: No i dont see error here. In fact, i was following a video and I wrote everything exactly same as its except his index file is .pnp, and mine is html.

Comment: ok, that is fine. You can check my answer. Hope it will help you.

Comment: your welcome @xxmdsk, you may accept Shadow's answer and give him and me up votes to our answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  I'll explain if it worked

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#datetime').datetimepicker();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--this must be declared first-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script> <!--this must be declared after jquery-->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.4/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="datetime">
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. so first thing I should declare jquery.js then put other plugin after it. The last will be css file right? So does it matter where i declare the javascript.js file?

Comment: No problem bro. Please don't forget to mark the check for my answer.

Comment: Yes. The page is like a human. It reads from the top to bottom. So the `js says` if you declare it first, "Hey, find the element with the id of `#datetime`", the js can't find it because it loads first before the `#datetime`, so you better load the `html` first before your `scripts`. Also, this is the one of the best practice in code placements.

Comment: @xxmdsk You should accept an answer with an explanation. So next time you know what to do.

Comment: dId I do it right? I already mark it and vote, but I am not sure why it did not show

Answer (score 0):

[Sorry, here is my folder with files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LNP1.png)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to reorder your js file inclusions like give below:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> <!--this must be in the top -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script> <!--This must be after jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>
```

Then,

Put your code inside document ready state.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#datetime").datetimepicker();
});
</script>
```

Comment: @ShadowFiend, I did not notice that at first look. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Do you see an error in JS console? If not, the script might work, but because the z-index is set to "auto" by default you might not see it. I had this problem while using modal pop-up in UIkit. If this is the case, you can fix it by setting z-index. Include the following to your CSS file:

```
.ui-timepicker-container {
    z-index: 1011 !important;
}
```